# Cannot change default python version in Windows 10

Tags: python, path, windows-10, environment-variables, system

I would like to modify the default version of Python that is used, system wide.
I thought that the way to do this was to change the ordering of my path variables. It does 
not make a difference though: 
Starting with my path, I have python 3 at the top, along with scripts as second (to allow 
for pip, virtualenv etc to be on the path). 
Using command prompt, and typing python, I get what is expected:

> Python 3.6.2 (v3.6.2:5fd33b5, Jul ..... etc

[image]

However, when I change the order of my path variables, moving python 2 to the top:

[image]

I still get python 3 when I type python.

I can confirm that the ordering of my path has not changed, using the following cmd:

> echo %path%

with this as the results:

[image]

Note, 
i.) I am not looking for tips for different python versions, using Docker, pipenv, virtualenv, conda, etc. I am trying to make sure I have control over which version of python is used, system-wide/ and or I am confused as to why the modification of the ordering of path variables does not change the ordering of the path variables.
ii.) Cmds: python3 and python2 do work. This question came out of a problem with python but it is about the path ordering not being modifiable.
iii.) I have restarted the computer each time, and it makes no difference. 
 Thank-you

Comment: The ordering of the `PATH` variables does matter, so something else must be going on here.

Comment: Have you restarted the command prompt? Changes won't apply if you don't.

Comment: @cwalvoort, exaclty, hence my question

Comment: @IOS_DEV yes (iii.)